# Consensus about a transaction set

Tags: transactions, scp

In the description of the transaction life cycle it is [mentioned](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#life-cycle) that:

> SCP resolves the differences between the various transaction sets
>   proposed and decides on the one transaction set that the network will
>   apply.

My understanding is that difference instances of `stellar-core` might decide to add different transactions in a transaction set, but why would that happen? Then, how specifically the servers reach a consensus about which transaction set is the *right* one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two distinct phases/sub-protocols with different purpose in SCP:

the **ballot protocol** ensures that if a quorum agrees to something, all nodes will agree to the same thing;

the **nomination protocol** is there to pick “interesting values” to feed into the ballot protocol.

An interesting value is constructed such that: it converges over time, values are likely to be confirmed by the quorum (not guaranteed, there are some edge cases that may cause a new value to be generated later to unblock the ballot protocol).

When the nomination protocol “starts”, nodes use whatever transactions they know about as a starting point and over the course of the consensus round resolve conflicts by merging transaction sets.

You can read more about this in the section “6.1 nomination protocol” in the [SCP white paper](https://www.stellar.org/papers/stellar-consensus-protocol.pdf)